Multicultural windows app with resources C#
I'm trying to make a multicultural windows app with resource, my code is something like this.
I have 3 .resx files: language.en.resx, language.es.resx, language.resx
I also have this class
public static class LangHelper
{
    private static ResourceManager _rm;
    static LangHelper() {
        _rm = new ResourceManager("prjMcadTools.App_GlobalResources.language", Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()); 
    }

    public static string GetString(string name) { 
        return _rm.GetString(name);
    }

    public static void ChangeLanguage(string language)
    {
        var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo(language);
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
        CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
    }
}

Firstly, I invoke a method to change the culture and then I invoke the method to get the string, however it always returns strings that are in the language.resx no matter of culture I set.
Where am I wrong, any suggestions?
Thank you
I expect to get the strings of the language file of the culture I set: for example if I set "es", I would expect to get the string of language.es.resx

It appears you are not constructing ResourceManager with changed parameters inside ChangeLanguage method. The ChangeLanguage in your code does nothing other than creating a local object which get destructed soon.
You need to add this line at the end of the method.
_rm = new ResourceManager($"prjMcadTools.App_GlobalResources.language.{language}", Assembly.GetExecuting Assembly());


hello thank for you answer,  Im trying to do your suggestion I execute the method with this parameter "en-US" but I still get the error , "prjMcadTools.App_LocalResources.language.en-US.resources" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "prjMcadTools" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.'

Your language.resx file should have an associated language.Designer.cs-file that contain autogenerated static properties for each translation string.
So in most cases you would use language.MyTranslationKey for accessing strings. This is the preferred method since the compiler will complain if there are errors, and it works better with IntelliSense and other IDE tools.
Note that you may need to set the "Access Modifier" in the resx to public if it is in another project.
Also note that changing language will not automatically update the UI to use the new strings. You can either decide that the user need to restart the application after changing language, or spend some effort to ensure everything is updated correctly. Tools like wpf localize extensions can make this a bit easier.
